# How to use other jquery source files in jquery thick box, e.g jquery calender

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I have a jquery thick box and its working fine

Now, how can i implement the jquery calender to a text field in the jquery thick box

follwing is my html code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('form#hotel_search_popup').ajaxForm({



        });


<form id="hotel_search_popup">
<input type="text" name="date"/>
</form
```

Comment: While i include the jquery source file like<script src>its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've included the jquery library you should just need to include the jqueryui file. Make sure you close the script tags properly. Also give your date input an ID attribute to use as the selector to assign the datepicker

e.g.

```
<script src="src"></script>
```

not

Then you should just need

```
$(function(){
    $('#date').datepicker();
});
```